# Group by command in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a file in this format

```
1 N
1 N
1 N
2 N
1 Y
1 N
2 N
1 Y
1 N
2 Y
```

Need to group it like below

```
1 Y 2
1 N 5
2 Y 1
2 N 2
```

(count of the 1 Y's)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi, Tried perl but couldn't complete it. Then worked with sort and got the answer.

sort filename | uniq -c | sort -nr

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{n[$0]++} END{for(i in n){print i ":" n[i]}' file
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the same, #salparadise #WeSee
Also found this 

sort filename | uniq -c | sort -nr

Answer (score 0):

perl oneliner:

```
perl -lne '$x{$_}++; END {print "$_ $x{$_}" for keys %x}'
```